# In Java, how I count the size of the download of a webpage during the download?

Tags: java, download, size, httpurlconnection

I want to do this:

I have a max limit size for donwload(eg.: 10MB). I start the download of a webpage. If the download of the page does not finish until the limit was reached, I stop the download.

I done a similar question here: [In Java, it's possible determine the size of a web page before download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902306/in-java-its-possible-determine-the-size-of-a-web-page-before-download), but it was to discover the size of the page before I start the download, but some servers don't send this information. Now I need to control during the donwload.

They told me to use *CountInputStream*. This is the way? I using *HttpUrlConnection*, so the download is not done with the *getInputStream*?

Comment: do you mean "web page" or do you mean "content via http"?  because as others have said, many pages now will have dynamic content that won't arrive via just reading a page byte by byte, only by interacting with it via javascript/etc.

Comment: Oh, only content via http. I dont need need images, scripts, css, etc. Only the HTML/generated content. The source code of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `HttpUrlConnection` to read from a remote resource over HTTP, this then implies that you are reading the data returned by the remote resource using `HttpUrlConnection.getInputStream()`.

To count the number of bytes read as you read from the connection, simply... count the number of bytes as you read from the inputStream. For example:

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = ...;
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[MAX_BYTES];
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
int bytesRead, totalRead = 0;
while (bytesRead != -1) {
    bytesRead = stream.read(dataBuffer, totalRead, bufferLength);
    totalRead += bytesRead;
    if (totalRead > MAX_BYTES) throw new FileTooBigException(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the web server supports it, you could look at the `Content-Length` header, that would tell you how big the thing would be:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

If the server/item doesn't support content length, you'd have to read the whole thing and just count bytes...

The answer you linked to seems to contain most of the rest of the information you'd need, isn't it almost exactly the same question as yours?

Comment: No, in that question I want to know the size before the download, now I need to count the bytes while I download to stop him if reachs a certain limit size.

Comment: But if you already know the size before, why even start the download?  If you're already downloading the file somehow, you have to be putting it *somewhere*, right?  and if so, can't you just count bytes as you read them?

Comment: Most of the servers don't send the size of the page, so I don't know the size. The only way to get the size is start the download and counting the bytes.

Comment: what's with the downvote?  my answer even has as a second recommendation "If the server/item doesn't support content length, you'd have to read the whole thing and just count bytes..." which is exactly what the other answers are saying to do..

Answer (score 1):

You can do an HTTP HEAD request, but that's only going to return the "Content-Length" of the web page.

Size of a web page is a funny thing, as a web page contains a lot of other documents (graphics for instance).  Content-Length is not quite the "entire size" of the document, and even if you ask the content length at this moment, it is no guarantee that the content length will be the same a mere millisecond later.

For static pages, content-length could probably be trusted; however, for dynamic content, I would recon that content-length is either sometimes wrong or always wrong.

Comment: doing head request will not transfer entire page, thus reducing the number of bytes over wire.

Comment: And if the server don't sends the content-lenght?

Comment: Then you must download the page.  I can't rightly understand how you would expect to know the length of such content without the system either telling you its length, or you measuring it yourself.  In the event that you want to "cut" off the content at your arbitrary limit, I hope you keep in mind that in HTML, half a document won't close its tags, and cannot be considered usable by many programs.  There is not guarantee that the first "part" of a document will even show anything without the "latter parts".

Comment: Yes, I know that I must download the page, my doubt is how I measure the downloaded size while downloading, not after the download is complete. About be incomplete, this is not important, I will discard these pages that overcome the limit. This is more to a caution if something pass the filters and begin the download of a big file, by example.

Comment: Read from the stream a byte at a time, and keep a counter which you increment for every byte read.  It really is as simple as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure HTTP 1.1 keep-alive is enabled (Connection: keep-alive) and the server agrees, the server is *obliged* to send a content-length.